# Canvas not working -- however no errors

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to run a simple truck simulator (sorry for the liking of trucks), but when I try, it seems to not work (also no errors). However, when I run the entire code in the edit section of  [Bill Mill's Canvas Tutorial](http://billmill.org/static/canvastutorial/ball.html), it works. In case if you say it's my browser, this doesn't show "Oops...":
    `<canvas id="canvas" width="420" height="440" style="border: 1px solid #000;">Oops...




JS:

    /*Truck Driving Simulator**/
    //set up the canvas
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var w = 420;
    var h = w+20;
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    var t = tr(250,250,20,40,'blue');
    function tr(iX,iY,iR,iColor){
        return{
            drawmove: function(){
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(iX, iY, iR, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
                ctx.fillStyle = iColor;
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
            }
        }
    }
    function p(){
        t.drawmove();
    }
    function init(){
        setInterval(function(){
            p();
        }, 60);
    }
    init();`

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yey4xdoq/
Also, even though it shows in the fiddle, it doesn't on my PC.
I:
1. Made sure my browser supports the canvas tag
2. Correctly linked my Js
3. Correctly called the canvas

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle where the problem is happening?

Comment: It isn't happening; but doesn't show :/

Comment: The JSFiddle works for me in Chrome...

Comment: Can you explain more about what isn't working? Do you see a circle?

Comment: the only thing that is not working is the color of the circle because you pass one argument more in the `tr` method. It should be `var t = tr(250,250,20,'blue');`

Comment: No. All I see is a box with a line (I added a line style to it.

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli Good point. I'll try that.

Comment: Also, in the actual html is your `<script>` tag below the `<canvas>` ? otherwise the `getElementById` will not work.

Comment: Please define "not working". If you expect something to move, notice, that `iX,iY,iR,iColor` are defined only once in your script.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Yes.

Comment: @Teemu That is parameters.

Comment: @Peter could you create a pasteBin (http://pastebin.com/) with all your html and copy the link here ?

Comment: @Peter Parameters? The values of `iX` and `iY` are never changed anywhere.

Comment: Gaby, the placement isn't the matter. I it works but not in my fashion.

Comment: Teemu, those are parameters. They are set to 250 in the X coordinate, and 250 in the Y coordinate.

Comment: Also, Teemu, I don't have a move function in my script. Do you see it anywhere?

Comment: Gaby, did you see what GregL said? If not look upwards. O_o